# Compress Image size JavaScript

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, html5-canvas

I am doing project where we can take snap shots from video. You can view my code snippet below.

```
             function snapshot(){
                context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, w, h);
                img = document.createElement("img");
                img.src = canvas.toDataURL();
             }
```

w,h are nothing but width and height of video. Those are calculated as shown below.

```
            video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {

               var ratio = video.videoWidth / video.videoHeight;
               w = video.videoWidth - 100;
               h = parseInt(w / ratio, 10);
               w= w-100; h= h-100;
               canvas.width = w;
               canvas.height = h;           
            }, false);
```

The base64 Image I am getting here is approximately 260kb. I want to reduce this image to below 80kb.

I tried using `canvas.toDataURL('image/png', 0.2)` but no use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quality setting is only valid when the type of image is either `jpeg` or `webp`. Try using the following:

```
canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 0.1);
```

For example, from the [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL):

> A Number between 0 and 1 indicating image quality if the requested
>   type is `image/jpeg` or `image/webp`. 
>   
> If this argument is anything else,
>   the default value for image quality is used. Other arguments are
>   ignored.

Answer (score 0):

[The specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#a-serialization-of-the-bitmap-as-a-file) and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL) say that the second argument is not supported for PNG images. The specification says the second argument is just for `image/jpeg`; MDN says `image/jpeg` or `image/webp`.

Note that browsers are not required to support anything other than PNG, and if you request something they don't support, they give back PNG. So you can do:

```
img.src = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 0.2);
```

...and you'll either get a JPEG low quality (`0.2` is really low), or a PNG ignoring the second argument.